# react native, react-navigation, TabNavigator, how to send a request when I change tab screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the`react-navigation` to control react-native App.

```
const MainTab = TabNavigator({
  Home: tabscreen(HomeScreen, '/home', 'home', 'home'),
  Chat: tabscreen(ChatScreen, '/chat', 'chat', 'chat'),
  Find: tabscreen(FindScreen, '/find', 'find', 'find'),
  Profile: tabscreen(ProfileScreen, '/profile', 'profile', 'profile')
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  swipeEnabled: false,
  animationEnabled: false,
  lazy: true,
  //...other configs
  tabBarOptions: {
    // tint color is passed to text and icons (if enabled) on the tab bar
    activeTintColor: '#1BBC9B',
    inactiveTintColor: '#9B9B9B',
    showIcon: true,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#F4F4F4',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      height: 49
    },
    labelStyle: {
      marginTop: 0,
      marginLeft: 0,
      marginRight: 0,
      marginBottom: 1.5
    }
  }
});



   const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainTab ,
    path: '/',
    navigationOptions: {
      // header: null,
      headerVisible: false,
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
  },

  ....

    {
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
      gesturesEnabled: true,
      headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerBackTitle: null,
  }
});
```

In the `Chat` tab, I send a request to the backend to get a list data in `ChatScreen`'s `componentDidMount` function.  It works well.
  When I navigate another screen from the `ChatScreen`, do something, and then go back to the `ChatScreen` by clicking the back button in the left top corner of another screen.I need to request the list data from the backend again, but the `componentDidMount` doesn't execute again.

If `ChatScreen` navigates to another screen named "A".   "A" screen navigate go back to the `ChatScreen`. I find the `ChatScreen` doesn't execute the `componentDidMount` function in this case.

My need is requesting the list data when I change the screen to the `ChatScreen`. Must I send the request in another `react lifecycle function`

One more thing, I am using the redux to control the state.

Comment: can u also add react-navigation tag?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet, you can follow issue [#51](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51) for this.

and it's in roadmap to v1 stable [#723](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/723)

as for workaround, you can use this [pmachawoski's](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51#issuecomment-302366381) that use high order component, to know if a tab is focused or not, but the problem with this is, it's always executed, not like `componentDidMount` that executed once.

Answer (score 0):

You should use onNavigationStateChange

link example here: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/69xm4p/react_navigation_tab_change_event/